# Array is storing too many values

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The program is intended to compare the previous inputs to the current to the. If an input has not been entered, the input will be stored at the next index of the team and stored, with the same index with a value. If the input was already entered, the value will be incremented 
Note: the array "score" was initialized as an int. the array "team" was initialized as a String. W

```
for (j = 0; !input.equals("x"); j++ )  // problem with j making too many on the list
    { // moves onto a new 
        System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)"); 
        input = scnr.nextLine();
        for (i = 0; i < team.length && !input.equals("x"); i++) 
        { // compares input against previous inputs
            if (team[i].equals(input)) 
            { // comparison issue FIXME
                score[i]++; 
                break;
            }
            else if (!team[i].equals(input) && score[j] == 0) 
            {
                team[j] = input;
                score[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a 2D `array`?

Comment: No, I am required to use 2 separate arrays.

Comment: Could you post the decleration of the `arrays`? (I'm assuming `score` is an `int[]` and `team` is a `String[]`?)

Comment: *"If you need further clarification, I will reply in the comments"* If you need to clarify the question, you need to **edit** the question, so readers can understand the question on it's own merit. Do not add clarifications in comments only.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Please post the actual code where you declared the `arrays`. (What is their fixed size? Did you populate the `arrays`? Without posting the actual code nobody but you will know the answer to these questions)

Comment: *"compare the previous inputs to the current to the."* To the what? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate approach you can use:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        String[] team = new String[MAX_SIZE];
        int[] score = new int[MAX_SIZE];
        int currentTeamCount = 0;
        boolean teamAlreadyExists = false;

        System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)");
        input = scnr.nextLine();
        while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            teamAlreadyExists = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < currentTeamCount; i++) {
                if (input.equals(team[i])) {
                    score[i]++;
                    teamAlreadyExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!teamAlreadyExists) {
                team[currentTeamCount] = input;
                score[currentTeamCount] = 1;
                currentTeamCount++;
            }

            System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)");
            input = scnr.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < currentTeamCount; i++) {
            System.out.println(team[i] + " " + score[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
Which team just won? (x to exit)
A
Which team just won? (x to exit)
B
Which team just won? (x to exit)
C
Which team just won? (x to exit)
D
Which team just won? (x to exit)
D
Which team just won? (x to exit)
D
Which team just won? (x to exit)
C
Which team just won? (x to exit)
B
Which team just won? (x to exit)
E
Which team just won? (x to exit)
F
Which team just won? (x to exit)
F
Which team just won? (x to exit)
x
```

Output:

```
A 1
B 2
C 2
D 3
E 1
F 2
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That answers everything I needed to know. Thanks for the help.